# I want to try org-mode. What's the shortest path from zero to typing?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, xemacs

I want to give emacs' org-mode a try. What is the shortest path for me to accomplish that?
Assume NO previous experience with emacs.

(I'm aware that other editors, like vim and textmate, have similar task lists. I'm specifically interested in learning about the emacs org-mode)

My laptop runs Win7 Home Premium x64

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I use Emacs (when I'm on Windows) with the official binaries at http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-22.3-barebin-i386.zip Just unzip to a directory and double click "runemacs".

In all the commands that follow, `C` stands for `Ctrl`.

Create a file ending in .org. If using recent Emacs, that will automatically start org-mode. You can create a file using `C-x C-f`.

Start creating outlines like this:

```
* Level 1
** Level 2
```

Collapse/Uncollapse outline levels with `TAB`

Todo's you can cycle by hitting `C-c C-t`

That's the basics, and pretty much all I know, but I already use it extensively :)

Have a look at the tutorials on http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/

Comment: `C-c T` doesn't work for me for cycling To-Do status. did you mean `C-c C-t` ?

Comment: @RubyTuesdayDONO Hi, it should be `C-c C-t` with lowercase `t`... Cheers

Comment: Groan:

The Emacs Windows initialization file "term/w32-win.el" could not be found in your Emacs installation.  Emacs checked the following directories for this file:

("../lisp" "c:/emacs/emacs-24.1/site-lisp" "C:/emacs/emacs-24.1/../site-lisp" "C:/emacs/emacs-24.1/lisp" "C:/emacs/emacs-24.1/leim")

When Emacs cannot find this file, it usually means that it was not installed properly, or its distribution file was not unpacked properly.
See the README.W32 file in the top-level Emacs directory for more information.

Comment: @MatthewLock, this may be fixed if  you download not the recommended "barebin", but the full archive (it worked for me with the same error): http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-22.3-bin-i386.zip, also newest version is recommended, now here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-24.4-bin-i686-pc-mingw32.zip

Answer (score 12):

I started org mode with an article in the linux journal and a very useful & simply tutorial.

[David O'Toole Org tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html)

[Get Organized with Emacs Org-mode](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9116?page=0,0)

Both sources give you in my opinion a superb and fast introduction to org mode.

Answer (score 9):

Start org mode with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>, or by visiting a file with the `.org` extension.

Type <kbd>C-h m</kbd> in an org mode buffer to see the (brief) mode description and (importantly) all of its key-bindings.

Type <kbd>C-h i m</kbd> `org` <kbd>RET</kbd> to read the Org Mode manual.

(Typing <kbd>q</kbd> will bury either of the *Help* or *info* buffers.)

Visit the web site at http://orgmode.org/ for more.

Comment: I just know the C-h m for displaying key binding. That is certainly useful Phils! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I found a very extensive list of youtube video regarding org-mode. See it here : [Org-Mode on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=org-mode&aq=f). Use the latest Emacs release, it already has org-mode installed. Create a file with .org extension. Now, type the title of the file, then start create these:

```
* Roles
** Role 1
*** Todo 1
*** Todo 2
*** Todo 3
** Role 2
*** Todo 1
*** Todo 2
```

While your cursor on Role1, press `TAB` and see the way org-mode hide/show the only relevant tree structure. Press tab again to toggle the visibility status.

Now, while you are in `Role 1`, type `C-x n s`, or the command `org-narrow-to-subtree`. It will only displayed `Role 1`. To get back, use the command `widen`, or `C-x n w`. 
I found it very helpful!

Lots of other great stuff in org-mode

By the way, you can easily convert and display in browser your org-file. Type : `org-export-as-html-and-open`. I use it a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Since others already mentioned how to install and start using org-mode, I would like to point you to the excellent [collection of tutorials](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/index.html) on Worg (it is a community driven documentation effort in the form of tutorials, How tos and other articles).

Answer (score 2):

Everyone starts Emacs without previous experience.You just need to:

1. Install Emacs
2. Install org-mode
3. Use org-mode to write something

I think both Emacs and org-mode are well documented.So if you have any trouble, read the official documents.

That's all. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

[Org-mode beginning at the basics](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org4beginners.html) sounds promising, it starts with

> ## The absolute minimum you need to know about Emacs
>
> The absolute minimum you need to know about Emacs, to be able to do
>   *anything*, is more then you need to know about many other applications.
>   But, you might compare it to a regular toy and lego. Lego is harder to
>   begin with (you start with a box with little plastic pieces), but in
>   the long run, you can do more with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a portable version with .emacs configure ready, which setup org mode, etc. It also included org sample file. I think that is a better start point.

http://nd.edu/~gsong/portable_emacs.html

Best,